How do I compute unified PADD on BLS12-377 using the twisted Edwards curve equations?
I'm learning ZKP these days and trying to write a program to calculate the results of point addition. I chose the BLS12-377 curve and started from the affine system. To make the situation simpler, I chose the two same points. Here are my codes:
m = (3 * x1 * x1) * inverse(2 * y1,p)
x3 = m * m - x1 - x2
y3 = y1 + m * (x3 - x1)
result_x = x3 % p
result_y = -y3 % p

(I know that the formula of PADD and PDBL is different so here I use the PDBL formula).
Following the paper Twisted Edwards Curve Revisited, I'm going to transform the curve into the form of the twisted Edwards curve, which is faster in calculating the PADD. However, I found that the results are different when using extended twisted Edwards coordinate systems. Here are my codes:
Z1 = 1
Z2 = 1
T1 = X1 * Y1 * Z1 % p
T2 = X2 * Y2 * Z2 % p
A = (Y1 - X1) * (Y2 - X2)
B = (Y1 + X1) * (Y2 + X2)
C = (k * T1 * T2)
D = (2 * Z1 * Z2)
E = (B - A)
F = (D - C)
G = (D + C)
H = (B + A)
X3 = (E * F) % p
Y3 = (G * H) % p
T3 = (E * H) % p
Z3 = (F * G) % p
inverse_element = inverse(Z3,p)
x_affine = (X3 * inverse_element) % p
y_affine = (Y3 * inverse_element) % p

Initially, I just let the twisted coordinates X1 and Y1 equal to x1 and y1 in the affine system. But the results were wrong. So I guess the affine coordinates should be transformed to the affine coordinates on the twisted Edwards curve correspondingly, and the above transformation is after this process. Is it right or are there other mistakes? If it's right, what should I do to transform the affine coordinates to the affine coordinates on the twisted Edwards curve? And where can I find the parameters related to this transformation?

Welcome to crypto-SE! The on-topic part of the question boils down to: how do I compute on BLS12-377 using twisted Edwards curve equations?  And yes coordinate change is required. The programming and debugging is off-topic, but some standard suggestion: include an assertion that your coordinates match the curve's equation. And isn't x2 on the second line supposed to be x1?

Thank you for your suggestion! I have revised my question. As for x2, it's equal to x1. I am sorry for the typo.

Note that not every elliptic curve can be represented in twisted Edwards form. Only those with a Montgomery representation can be so transformed. Fortunately, BLS12-377 can be put in this form per the following sagemath.
p = 0x01ae3a4617c510eac63b05c06ca1493b1a22d9f300f5138f1ef3622fba094800170b5d44300000008508c00000000001
K = GF(p)
a = K(0x00)
b = K(0x01)
E = EllipticCurve(K, (a, b))
G = E(0x008848defe740a67c8fc6225bf87ff5485951e2caa9d41bb188282c8bd37cb5cd5481512ffcd394eeab9b16eb21be9ef, 0x01914a69c5102eff1f674f5d30afeec4bd7fb348ca3e52d96d182ad44fb82305c2fe3d3634a9591afd82de55559c8ea6)
E.set_order(0x12ab655e9a2ca55660b44d1e5c37b00159aa76fed00000010a11800000000001 * 0x170b5d44300000000000000000000000)
E2,g=E.montgomery_model(morphism=true)
E2
g.x_rational_map()

Which shows that we can map from BLS12-377 to the curve $y^2 = x^3 + Ax^2 + x$ where $A=$30567070899668889872121584789658882274245471728719284894883538395508419196346447682510590835309008936731240225793 via the map $x\mapsto$ 248475402379746130719945538765007239444978355512008232241589749868217661949558673547465357861137023812196574716246$x$+248475402379746130719945538765007239444978355512008232241589749868217661949558673547465357861137023812196574716246
Given our Montgomery form we can birationally map to the twisted Edwards curve $$(A+2)x^2+y^2=1+(A-2)x^2y^2$$
via the map
$$(x,y)\mapsto (x/y,(x-1)/(x+1))$$
(see Twisted Edwards Elliptic Curves for Zero-Knowledge Circuits Theorem 5 for example).

So, Sagemath finally has montgomery_model
